# VBA: Sending emails with variable in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to create a data macro in Access 2010 that would send an email with variable values in its body?

What I am trying to do is this: When a specific field is changed than an email is sent stating that the field has been changed and who has changed it (based on a parameter captured at login). Creating the email data macro is simple enough, but I cannot see how to put anything but static text into the body!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the body row and start to type the equal sign "`=`"

There will appear a wizard button on the right side of the row, where you can set up your body text with an expression.